# Python - post request fails when using requests

Tags: python, api, python-requests

When using the shell, I can successfully create a new user by running

`curl --user administrator:pasword "Content-Type: application/json" https://localhost:8080/midpoint/ws/rest/users -d @user.json`

However when I try to do the same thing in python using requests, I get a 200 response and no user is created.

This is the script I am using:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = open('user.json')
response = requests.post('https://localhost:8080/midpoint/ws/rest/users', headers=headers, data=data, auth=('Administrator', 'password'))
print(response)
```

To me they look the same. What is different in the python request that is stopping the user from being created?

Comment: administrator vs Administrator? pasword vs password?

Comment: i think you need to parse data with json.loads ..

Comment: Sorry, a/Administrator pasword/password are typos...

Comment: try this : import requests
import json
with open('user.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

Answer (score 0):

I compare the post date with `curl` and `python requests`.And i found the difference.

> CURL: {"user" : "hero","pd":30}
>
> Requests: pd=30&user=hero

Then this is my test.

```
import requests
import json
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

with open('user.json') as j:
    data = json.load(j)

response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080', 
                        headers=headers, 
                        json = data, 
                        auth=('Administrator', 'password'))
print(response.headers)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately when I try with the above I still get a response 200 instead of 201 created, and no user is created...

Comment: @buffcat i have change  to `json = data` , may be it can help you

Answer (score 0):

I think using json = data would work as well, but I was finally successful using json dumps: data=json.dumps(data)